# Does Google Analytics count app upgrades as new installs?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

We're using GA for social media app and there is a huge difference in the amount of new users(installs) in GA and the amount of installs in iTunes analytics

The amount of views in sign-up screen is less than the amount of new users for chosen time range, which is more confusing. As a new user you just can't bypass sign-up screen

There is such thing as User explorer that gives you a list of events and views in chronological order for each and every user. I looked through all the users and their action for one specific day and it seems like app upgrade is counted as new install. 
Users that have 'Acquisition day' that i've chosen as a date range for GA were not on sign-up page at all. It's like a new user gets in the app feed  screen bypassing sign-up screen.

This could be a situation where user is logged in and upgrade an app. In this case user will stay in the app after it's updated

Is there a way to detect and differentiate between new install and app upgrade?